# Open neighborhood of product of first order thickening

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $B_0\hookrightarrow B$ be a first order thickening, i.e. it's a closed immersion and the ideal sheaf $I$ satisfies $I^2=0$. Let $X$ be a projective variety. Is it true that every open neighborhood of $X\times B_0$ inside $X\times B$ is already $X\times B$ itself? I consider everything as schemes over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You're completely right, I forgot mentioning that I consider the schemes to be over the complex numbers. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "Is it true that every open neighborhood of X×B0 inside X×B is already X×B itself?"

**Answer:** It holds for arbitrary affine varieties: Let $X:=Spec(A), B:=Spec(R)$ and $B_0:=Spec(R/I)$ with $I^2=0$.

There is a canonical projection map

$$p: X\times B \rightarrow B$$

and by definition it follows $X\times B_0:=p^{-1}(B_0)\cong Spec(A\otimes R/I(A\otimes R))$.
Since $I^2=0$ it follows $J^2=0$ where $J:=I(A\otimes R)$. Hence $X\times B_0:=Spec(A\otimes R/J)$. There is an equality in $X\times B$

$$V(J^2)=V(J) \cup V(J)=V(J),$$

hence if $V(J) \subseteq U \subseteq X \times B$ with $U$ an open set, it follows

$$V(J)=V(J^2)=V((0))=X\times B \subseteq U.$$

In general if $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is quasi projective and if

$$X \times B_0 \subseteq U \subseteq X \times B$$

is an open subscheme, let $U_i:=Spec(A_i)$ be an affine open cover of $X$. Since $U_i \times B_0 \subseteq U$ for all $i$, it follows $U_i \times B \subseteq U$ for all $i$, hence $X \times B \subseteq U$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your argument in the last paragraph should also work for $B$ quasi-projective, right?

Comment: @ipreferpi42 - If $B$ is quasi projective with a quasi coherent  ideal sheaf $I$ with $I^2=0$ let $B_0:=Spec(\mathcal{O}_B/I)$. It seems the argument above applies to $X \times B_0$.